# Not processing php file for highlight_file function

Tags: php

showcode.php

```
<?php
$source = $file;
highlight_file( $source );
?>
```

showcode.php?file=to_study.php

In some cases to_study.php file gets processed and I do not get the highlighted code. Error something like:

```
Warning: Unterminated comment starting line 197 on line 3
```

I do not want to process the to_study.php file. I just want it to be highlighted in browser.

Comment: To highlight code, the code needs to be parsed. If there's a syntax error in the code, it cannot be parsed properly, which leads to this error. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Does the $source code compile?

Comment: Is it possible to read the code line by line and high-light it? By doing this I can skip the errors.

Comment: Highlighting/parsing incorrect syntax is mostly meaningless, precisely because the syntax is ambiguous/wrong and cannot be properly understood, therefore highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What php version are you using? You should get highlighted code even when there are syntax errors. Just disabling displaying errors or setting `error_reporting` to 0 should prevent this warning to disrupt highlighted source.